# Changing div backgrounds while scrolling (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jQuery! I'm using ***jquery-3.1.1.min*** and ***jquery.color-2.1.0***.

I got a webpage with at least a "top" div and a "footer" div. Both are set as fixed. What I want: when you scroll down the background of both divs need to change background. When you scroll all the way up again it should be changed to the original background.

I have the following jQuery code. The first part works fine; The backgrounds change when I scroll down. My question is how I get them to change again when I scroll up.

I've tried it with an 'else' in the code below, but that didn't work unfortunately. Who can help? Not good with jQuery.

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop() > 90){
      $(".top").animate({"background-color":"#101010"},'slow');
      $(".footer").animate({"background-color":"#101010"},'slow');
   }else{
      $(".top").animate({"background-color":"rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.8)"},'slow');
      $(".footer").animate({"background-color":"rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.8)"},'slow');
   }
});
```

Comment: The background you have in the second else is the same, only with an 80% opacity. Is that what you are looking to do? Try outputing to the console log in the browser to see when the scroll is being called and if its getting to else statement.

Comment: Yes they have opacity on default. When I scroll down it changes to #101010 but when I scroll up nothing is happening. I don't think the else is working at all.

Comment: Have you confirmed? The scrollTop is either above 90 or its not hitting the scroll function at all. If you create a fiddleJS example, it would be easier to see what you might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it myself after a lot of trying. First of all I used the "else if" statement.

```
if($(this).scrollTop() > 89){
   //change backgrounds here
}else if($(this).scrollTop() < 90){
   //change backgrounds back
}
```

It then worked but there was a big delay. After some Googling I found out it's being called several times a second so I solved that by using the Stop() function:

```
$(".top").stop().animate({"background-color":"rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.8)"},'slow');
```